# How to implement Type.​Is​Primitive Property of Type in Net Standard 1.3

Tags: c#, .net-standard

I need to use the Type.​Is​Primitive Property to check if a current type is one of the primitives types. I'm targeting Net Standard 1.3 as it is the required Net Standard version in some of the projects that will use this package. As I can see [Dot Net API Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isprimitive?view=netstandard-1.3) it is not supported in this version. Is there any alternative implementation that I can use? Or a way to be sure that a type is a primitive one? Thanks

Comment: What do you intend to do with this information?

Comment: `type.GetTypeInfo().IsPrimitive` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.typeinfo.isprimitive?view=netstandard-1.3#System_Reflection_TypeInfo_IsPrimitive

Comment: The list of primitives is actually quite short so just make an extension method that checks it the current type is any of Boolean, Byte, SByte, Int16, UInt16, Int32, UInt32, Int64, UInt64, IntPtr, UIntPtr, Char, Double or Single.

Comment: @vcsjones Thanks I did not noticed that it is now in the TypeInfo. Thanks, can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `type.GetTypeInfo().IsPrimitive` in netstandard1.3. Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.typeinfo.isprimitive?view=netstandard-1.3#System_Reflection_TypeInfo_IsPrimitive